# How to disable this option in chrome via program

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

I am recording the video using screen-recorder in my framework, but to do that I have to disable the option `Use hardware acceleration when available` but since I clear profile every time when sanity run finishes, this selection also gets deleted along with the profile. Is there any way I can set this option when I am initiating the browser? Like we are disabling the `prompt_for_download`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may start chrome with `--disable-gpu` flag

Comment: No, it's not working for me, Is it working for you?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, how did you check if it's not working? Using the `--disable-gpu` flag, I didn't see a change to the "use hardware acceleration when available" setting. However, if I go to the "chrome://gpu/" page, everything has been switched to disabled.

Comment: @JustinKo Yes, you are right, It's not changing anything in 'use hardware acceleration when available' but video is being recorded now.